# CSS not showing shadow of image when page rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce

```
 style="width:280px; height:250px; margin-left:20%; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px
 #ccc; -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px
 #ccc; -khtml-box-shadow: 15px 15px 10px #ccc;"
```

I used this inline CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as though you're using some CSS 3. The Salesforce PDF Render Engine only supports CSS 2.1. You'll need to revise your CSS to CSS 2.1 levels.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [link](http://www.antennahouse.com/CSSInfo/CSS-Page-Tutorial-en.pdf) and find `Chapter 14. Shadowed boxes`, samples provided there should help you.

Also, maybe you'll have to put the `image` tag inside a `div` or a `p` or some other tag that correctly renders the shadows. I haven't tested this, it's just a suggestion that you can try.

Comment: Not worked in rendered page